# Oracle username pattern match - for different usernames in staged environments

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle11g, permissions

I'm used to having the same username for an application process across all databases - this way you can deploy a stored procedure and grant it permissions, and the same script can be used everywhere.

The problem I'm trying to solve is granting permissions - the scenario is:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON b.procedure_name TO APP_USER_DEV
```

I'm working on an Oracle database, where for whatever reason, the DBAs have decided to use different usernames for each stage of the process. So you have something like:

```
APP_USER_DEV
APP_USER_TEST
APP_USER_PROD
```

Which is kind of silly, but outside of my sphere of influence. When given lemons, we make lemonade! So here is a chance to do something a little creative.

Now I want to keep using the one script. The junior dev guys in my team naturally say:

> If we have different usernames for each environment, then we need a different script for each environment.

I can understand the logic, but this is a little risky, and I think we can do better, ie one script for all environments.

What I want to do is have a regex that does a partial match on the username. On Sybase I'd do something like:

```
declare @myusername varchar(20) 

select @myusername = user_name from sys.sysuserperm where user_name like 'APP_USER_%'

GRANT EXECUTE ON b.procedure_name TO @myusername
```

My question is - how can I do this on Oracle? (11g)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare
  v_procedure_name varchar2(100) := 'my_proc';
begin
for c in (select username from all_users where username like 'APP_USER_%') loop
  execute immediate 'grant execute on '||v_procedure_name||' to '||c.username;
  end loop;
end;
```

Edit:
Version with hardcoded  proc-name and without loop

```
declare
  v_user_name varchar2(100) ;
begin
  select username
    into v_user_name
    from all_users 
   where username like 'APP_USER_%';
  execute immediate 'grant execute on my_proc to '||v_user_name;
end;
```

Comment: This is cool - what if I know the proc-name - can't I just hard-code it? Do I need to declare it before?

Comment: And if there is just one user- do I need a loop - can't I just select the first result?

Comment: Sure, you can hardcode as much as you like ;)
As far as I understood you, there are three users 
APP_USER_DEV, APP_USER_TEST, APP_USER_PROD. That is why I made the loop.

Comment: Sure - but only one of them in each environment. So the DEV one has the DEV user etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use the dynamic query with `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` like below

```
create or replace procedure grantuser(user varchar2)
IS 
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT EXECUTE ON procedure_name to' || user;
END;
```

just calling the above procedure like

```
exec grantuser('APP_USER_DEV');
```

will grant the permission

Comment: How does that handle the different usernames for the different staged environments in the one file?

Comment: How you are handling the different enviroments, whether they are different database??

Comment: They're on different hosts.